# how to convert string json array to int array android studio

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have program like this

```
String[] hello; Integer[] yAxisData2;
```

i want to convert string json array to int array. , how to convert string hello[i] to int array ?

```
private void generateY(){
    mApiInterface.getGulaDarah(idUser).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                try{
                    JSONArray jsonRes = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
                    hello = new String[jsonRes.length()];

                    for(int i=0; i<jsonRes.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject =  jsonRes.getJSONObject(i);
                        hello[i] =jsonObject.getString("guladarah_acak");
                        yAxisData2[]=Integer.parseInt(hello[i]);
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "guladarah_acak"  what is structure of this....

Comment: Please post structure of json. if "guladarah_acak" is string and you need to convert it to `int` you can use `parseInt()` but you need to initialize `yAxisData2` like you initialized `hello` with it's size and then you can assign a value with index.

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't quite clear so I'll provide a few solutions and hopefully at least one will prove to be of use.

If what you want is to convert an array of Strings to an array of Integers you can use;

```
private int[] convert(String[] stringArray) {
    int integerArray[] = new int[stringArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        integerArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]); // You'll need to handle errors here
    }

    return integerArray;
}
```

Although I would suggest you use a List instead.

*Alternatively you could use Lambda Expressions, available from Java 8;*

`int[] arrayOfInts = Arrays.asList(arrayOfStrings).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`

Otherwise if what you want is to convert a single String to an array of Integers you can use;

```
public int[] convert(String stringToConvert) {
    int[] intArray = new int[stringToConvert.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < stringToConvert.length(); i++){
        intArray[i] = stringToConvert.charAt(i) - '0';
    }

    return intArray;
}
```